# GroupBy a list of strings

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
class A {
    private List<String> keys;
    private String otherData;
    private int otherDate2;

    // getter and setters for each
}
```

For this class I have a simple list filled with some data. `List<A> listOfA`.
Now I want to convert this data to a map. `Map<String, List<A>>`

Currently we using a bunch of methods to archive this in a very complicated way. I think, we can solve it with a simple `stream()`-operation.

I tried this

```
// first
listOfA.stream()
    .collect(Colletors.groupingBy(a -> a.getKeys()))
// produces a Map<String, List<A>>     

// second
listOfA.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.getKeys().stream())
    .collect(Colletors.groupingBy(string -> string))
// produces a Map<String, List<String>>
```

What is the right way for this situation?

Edit: To be clear, I want a `Map<String, List<A>>`.

Comment: Which one suits your need?

Comment: It depends on your grouping criteria. Does grouping by `keys` make sense as you would group by lists of strings?

Comment: `A.keys` are (someties) equals. And I want to group same keys together.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, you want an entry in the resulting map for each entry in the `keys` list of the `A` instance?

Comment: Yes. A map, with the keys itself from `A.keys` (not as list).

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, if `keys` contains `[value,value2]` you want map with `{[value1= A()],[value2=A()]}` is that right? each value in `list` should be `key` in map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need streams for this. It's easier this way:

```
Map<String, List<A>> result = new HashMap<>();

listOfA.forEach(a -> a.getKeys().forEach(key -> 
        result.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(a)));
```

This iterates outer and inner lists and fills a `Map` using `computeIfAbsent`, which creates an empty list if there is still no value for the given key, then `A` instances are simply added to the corresponding list.

Comment: It is indeed very neat and it is a good example of Java 8 new methods that beyond streams allow to write conciser code.

Comment: Yeah, the `.computeIfAbsent()` method is very nice methode.

Comment: @davidxxx that is his second name, *without streams* ;)

Answer (score 3):

The first code will group by `Map<List<String>, List<A>>`  and not `Map<String, List<A>>`.
The second code makes no sense : you group strings by themselves...

A simple way would be creating the set of all possible key-A couples.
You could use a `Map` for each couple but it looks like an overhead.
`SimpleImmutableEntry` that represents a key and value suits better.
Once you get the whole couples, you can easily group A elements by key.

You could try something like :

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

    // ...
    List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfA.add(new A(Arrays.asList("1", "2"), "foo1", 1));
    listOfA.add(new A(Arrays.asList("2", "3"), "foo2", 2));
    listOfA.add(new A(Arrays.asList("3", "4"), "foo3", 3));

    Map<String, List<A>> map =
    listOfA.stream()
           .flatMap(a -> a.keys.stream()
                               .map(k -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(k, a)))
           .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), mapping(e -> e.getValue(), toList())));

    map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key=" + k + ", value=" + v + "\n"));
```

Output :

> key=1, value=[A [keys=[1, 2], otherData=foo1, otherDate2=1]]
>
> key=2, value=[A [keys=[1, 2], otherData=foo1, otherDate2=1], A
>   [keys=[2, 3], otherData=foo2, otherDate2=2]]
>
> key=3, value=[A [keys=[2, 3], otherData=foo2, otherDate2=2], A
>   [keys=[3, 4], otherData=foo3, otherDate2=3]]
>
> key=4, value=[A [keys=[3, 4], otherData=foo3, otherDate2=3]]

Comment: This solution is working and is exactly what Iam asking for. But its also very complicated. The answert from Federico Peralta Schaffner is simpler. So he got the "right answer". Its only one answer possible, but thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to group given collection by some field, and each group could contain multiple objects. This is part of my `GroupUtils`:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Using example.

You have following class:

```
class A {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

and to group collection of this class, you could with:

```
List<A> collection = Collections.emptyList();
Map<String, List<A>> groupedById = GroupUtils.groupMultipleBy(collection, A::getId);
```

***P.S.***

To give you more options, this relative part of my `GroupUtils`:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class GroupUtils {

    public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier) {
        return groupMultipleBy(data, classifier, Function.identity());
    }

    public static <K, V, S> Map<K, List<S>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier, Function<V, S> mapper) {
        return groupMultipleBy(data, classifier, mapper, Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <K, V, S, R extends Collection<S>> Map<K, R> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier,
                                                                               Collector<S, ?, R> downstream) {
        return groupMultipleBy(data, classifier, (Function<V, S>)Function.identity(), downstream);
    }

    public static <K, V, S, R extends Collection<S>> Map<K, R> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier,
                                                                               Function<V, S> mapper, Collector<S, ?, R> downstream) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.mapping(mapper, downstream)));
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> groupSingleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> keyMapper) {
        return groupSingleBy(data, keyMapper, Function.identity());
    }

    public static <K, V, S> Map<K, S> groupSingleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> keyMapper, Function<V, S> valueMapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper));
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `classifier` and how I have to use it?

Comment: @user6537157 See example

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your way. Its too complicated. The method-body so complex, that nobody can understand `public static <K, V, S, R extends Collection<S>> Map<K, R> groupMultipleBy`.

Comment: No problem. This is your choice how to solve your issue. My solution is not more complicated than standard collect group by.